# R: dlply,function(x), and if commands

Tags: r

I'm am trying to generate severate `lm()` using a `dlply` command.
`dlply()` subsets my `DF` by two variables: "SITE" and "SP". For every combination I would like to calculate a linear model, and save the slope and coefs in a list via `summary()`.

The linear model is calculated on a numeric value "IA" and a factor "YEAR". My problem comes from the fact that YEAR can have one value depending on the subset, resulting in an error:

> ```
>  Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
>   contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
> ```

So I'm trying to add a if/else command to ignore the subsets where YEAR have only one value, and calculate `lm()` only when `length(YEAR)` is different of 1.

But my command doesnt get rid of the error. What is wrong in my command?
Here is my code:

```
q<-dlply(SUBTOT, .(SITE, SP),function(x){
  if (length(x$YEAR)==1){m<-NULL
print(m)}    
  else{m <-lm(IA ~ YEAR, x)
  summary(m)}
  })
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: here is the number of levels of "YEAR" for the ten first "x" combinations.

```
q<-dlply(SUBTOT, .(SITE, SP),function(x){
   length(unique(x$YEAR))})

> q[1:10]
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 6
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 8
[1] 3
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but have you tried using an `ifelse` instead of the `if` and `else`?

Comment: `ifelse` seems to return logical strings, which does'nt suit to my command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
dlply(SUBTOT, .(SITE, SP), function(x) ifelse(nrow(x) > 1, summary(lm(IA ~ YEAR, x)), ""))
```

Comment: Hi! It worked with `length(unique(x$YEAR)) > 1` instead of `nrow(x) > 1`. Thanks!